# Getting " No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it " on minecraft server

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, minecraft, x11

Im trying to turn on a minecraft server using google cloud.

This is the error that occurs when I start it
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzhHU.png)

I've already tried these:

```
unset DISPLAY

export DISPLAY=:0.0

export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

and still get `java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.` or `java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`

Also when I use `echo $DISPLAY` it just prints a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to ./run.sh instead of ./start.sh.